# Can i show the packages installed in node on chef-server web user interface?

Tags: chef-infra

I need to show the packages installed in the node on my chef server web user interface. I am using chef stand alone enterprise chef. Is there any way to show the Packages installed in the node on Web User Interface of chef server.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot see the packages installed on some node through web interface. The things you can see are *attributes*, *run list* and *expanded run list* (where all the roles are substituted with recipes they include).

The only way to see packages, is to login to your node and ask package manager.

Comment: I think puppet has the option to show the packages installed in the node where client are running If chef also have a option to show packages status will be help full. Somebody need this thing also.

Comment: There are ohai community plugins available which will add package information into the node object. See: http://docs.opscode.com/community_plugin_ohai.html

Answer (score 3):

You can write an own [ohai](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai.html) plugin that fills an attribute like *packages* with entries read from the output of a platform-agnostic function (reading `dpkg -l` or friends on other systems).

Such attributes are automatically saved to the Chef server.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I wrote [an Ohai plugin](https://github.com/meineerde-cookbooks/ohai-system_packages) that fetches data about installed packages and provides them as node attributes (that are subsequently saved to the chef server) and can be analyzed there.

The only restriction here is that it gathers the information before the chef run really starts. Thus, if you install packages during your chef run, it will not be reflected in the the final data.